# get the value of <select> without submitting on the same page using php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Hope someone can help me.. 
i made my program more simpler so that everybody will understand..
i want my program to get the value of the  without submitting, i know that this can only be done by javascript or jquery so I use the onChange, but what I want is  when i select an option the value should be passed immediately on the same page but using php..

```
<select id="id_select" name="name" onChange="name_click()">
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
</select>

<script>
function name_click(){
value_select = document.getElementById("id_select").value;
}
</script>
```

and then i should pass the value_select into php in post method.. i dont know how i will do it.. please help me..

Comment: `then i should pass the value_select into php in post method` where is this code? Are you making an AJAX request or just submitting the form normally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this using PHP without submitting the page.  PHP code executes on the server **before** the page is rendered in the browser.  When a user then performs any action on the page (e.g. selects an item in a dropdown list), there is no PHP any more.  The only way you can get this code into PHP is by submitting the page.

What you *can* do however is use javascript to get the value - and then fire off an AJAX request to a php script passing the selected value and then deal with the results, e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my_select').on('change', do_something);
});

function do_something() {
    var selected = $('#my_select').val();
    $.ajax({
        url:        '/you/php/script.php',
        type:       'POST',
        dataType:   'json',
        data:       { value: selected },
        success:    function(data) {
            $('#some_div').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

With this code, whenever the selected option changes in the dropdown, a POST request will be fired off to your php script, passing the selected value to it.  Then the returned HTML will be set into the div with ID `some_div`.

Comment: ok.. i have actually used ajax.. but the problem is i really need to get the value back in php.. so from the ajax.. what can i put on the success: which gets the value and throw into a variable PHP?

Comment: @Krishna You CANNOT get the selected value into a variable in PHP _on the same page_.  Full stop.

Comment: oh so its not really possible.. anyway thank you soo much for the advice.. i guess ill stick with this..

Answer (score 0):

not sure ..but i guess ajax is what you need..

```
<script>
function name_click(){
  value_select = $("#id_select").val();
  $.post('path/to/your/page',{"value":value_select},function(data){
     alert('done')
 })

}
</script>
```

PHP

```
$value=$_POST['value']; //gives you the value_select data
```

Comment: ok.. i have actually used ajax.. but the problem is i really need to get the value back in php.. so from the ajax.. what can i put on the success: which gets the value and throw into a variable PHP?

Comment: ooppss i forgot to add that part.. anyways i updated my answer... the value that is sent to PHP is the second argument.. you can get that in PHP by `$_POST['value']`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion go with jquery. Try with this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#id_select").change(function(){
            var url = 'http:\\localhost\getdata.php'; //URL where you want to send data
            var postData = {'value' : $(this).value};
            $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data : postData,            
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                   //
                },
                error: function(e) {
                   console.log(e.message);
                }
            });
        })
    })
</script>
```

In getdata.php

```
<?php
 var $value = $_POST['value'];

// you can do  your logic

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Post with ajax as Alex G was telling you (+1) and then handle the post with PHP. You can define a callback in Javascript which will run when the page responds.