# Get the value from a listbox in php in the same page

Tags: php, html, database, listbox

I searched and searched the internet for help but I didn't get it so I'm posting here. I've got a select option thing in my code and I want to get the value of it so I can use it in a query, but I don't know how to get the value from the select option in the same page. So how can I get the value from this select? I'll give you the code to my select.

```
<select name="tamanho">

    <?php

        $sqltamanhos="SELECT * FROM detalhes_produtos WHERE cod_produto ='$codigo'";
        $resultadoo=odbc_exec($ligaBD,$sqltamanhos);
        while (odbc_fetch_row($resultadoo))
        {
            $tamanho = odbc_result($resultadoo,2);

        ?>
    <option value ="<?php echo $tamanho; ?>"> <?php echo $tamanho; ?> </option>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: `action=""` and GET/POST array? with `isset()`.

Comment: use var_dump to know the content of a variable https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.var-dump.php

Comment: Hey thank you for the reply ! Doesnt get/post only works in another pages??

Comment: I dont understand @MikeVelazco

Comment: I don't know if you know how does forms works, if not, first check this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: GET/POST works in any page, either on the same page or another. It just depends on how it's setup. My first comment basically solves/answers this question.

Comment: If you don't want that the data to be sent to the server you must use JavaScript not PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the value of select box via posting that value in the form(get/post method).

```
<form method="get" action="">
<select name="tamanho">
   <?php
     $sqltamanhos="SELECT * FROM detalhes_produtos WHERE cod_produto ='$codigo'";
     $resultadoo=odbc_exec($ligaBD,$sqltamanhos);
     while (odbc_fetch_row($resultadoo)){
           $tamanho = odbc_result($resultadoo,2);?>
           <option value ="<?php echo $tamanho; ?>"><?php echo $tamanho; ?> </option>
   <?php }?>
</form>
```

and get the value via

```
$value=$_GET['tamanho'];
```

you can also check this [get the value of <select> without submitting on the same page using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610023/get-the-value-of-select-without-submitting-on-the-same-page-using-php?rq=1)